# iPad: How to create a different icon for iOS 7?

Tags: icons, ios7

On iOS 7 for iPhone, there is a new app icon size: 120x120. I use this size to create an iOS 7-specific icon. On iOS 6 it will automatically take the "old" 114x114 icon, and on iOS 7 this new 120x120 image.

I want to do the same for an iPad app. Unfortunately I cannot do the same trick here because the icon dimensions didn't change! It is still 72x72 and 144x144 (Retina).

Does anyone know how I can make the icon look different on both iOS 6 and iOS 7?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about something under NDA.

Comment: http://blog.manbolo.com/2013/08/15/new-metrics-for-ios-7-app-icons

Comment: Questions covered by a third party NDA are not offtopic in StackOverflow. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/94488/162235

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use "asset catalog" (you can select that from general on your target).

That would create an images.xcassets on your project there you can easily drag your icon designs for pre iOS 7 and for iOS 7.

Comment: Is this backwards compatible with iOS 6?

Comment: It does not seem to be possible to supply a different icon for iOS 6 and iOS 7 for iPad using the asset catalog. (It does work for iPhone though). Maybe it is not possible at all because there is absolutely no iPad that will be stuck on iOS 6. For iPhone you will have the 3GS that is stuck on iOS 6, therefore you can give your app the old icon for just that device.

Comment: @TomvanZummeren I have this option under "AppIcon", I can clearly select the icons for 6 and prior to that. iPad 1 can't be upgraded to 6 and you can still compile to iOS 5...

Comment: Remove and recreate the asset catalogue, the one from the project template lacks some of the presets.

Comment: I don't know what the problem was, but now I see it in the Asset Catalog. As it turns out, iPad DOES use a different size for the app icons. As suggested by @sup it's 152x152 instead of 144x144, so you could also do this without the Asset Catalog. But it IS the best way to do it. Thanks!

Comment: @Rajeev and idan, I cant seem to be able to set images with xcassets. Can you tell me the method to do this?

Comment: Tom - "Maybe it is not possible at all because there is absolutely no iPad that will be stuck on iOS 6." That’s not true. The original iPad (Non-Retina) can’t be upgraded to iOS6 and it isn’t compatible with iOS7 either.

Comment: right click and add new app icon in the xcassets - then instead of 3 templates, you get 9.

Answer (score 7):

Xcode 5 added asset catalogs (.xcassets) which remove the need to follow naming conventions when adding images to your app.

When the WWDC videos are back up on the developer site, take a look at `400 - Whats new in Xcode 5`

Comment: .xcassets is discussed in the video at 9:47 and 13:13, if you don't want to watch the entire thing

Answer (score 6):

As evidenced by iOS 7 screenshots around the web, the iPad icons have increased in size to 76x76 and 152x152. So just use those sizes for your iOS 7 icons and the old sizes for iOS 6 and earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Use AlliOSIconsWithProperName application which will provide you all the icons based on information provided [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1686/_index.html). Get the [application from here](https://github.com/rptwsthi/AlliOSIconsWithProperName), and follow the instructions in readme file to create all the required icons for iOS application.