# iOS App Submission, Invalid Image Sizes

Tags: ios, icons, appstore-approval

I just received the following message with my iOS app submission:

> Invalid Image - For iOS applications, icons included in the binary
>   submission must be in the PNG format.
>
> -If your application supports the iPhone device family, you must include square icons of the following dimensions: 57x57 pixels and
>   120x120 pixels.
>
> -If your application supports the iPad device family, you must include square icons of the following dimensions: 72x72 pixels, 76x76 pixels
>   and 152x152 pixels

I assume that these are the new image sizes that will be required for iOS 7.  Does anyone know what the naming convention will be for the 3 iPad images?  And is it necessary to still include the old image sizes as well, 114x114 and 144x144?

Thanks!

Comment: use this application (https://github.com/rptwsthi/AlliOSIconsWithProperName/archive/master.zip) to create all the icons required for ios application and incorporate that in your application.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Yes, there are new icon sizes for iOS 7. See this article: [New Metrics for iOS 7 App Icons](http://blog.manbolo.com/2013/08/15/new-metrics-for-ios-7-app-icons). It explains (near the bottom of the article) the sizes you need for iPhone and iPad:

> If you want to target only iOS 7, you just need 76 x 76, 120 x 120 and 152 x 152 icon sizes. If you want to target also iOS 6, you’ll need 57 x 57, 72 x 72, 76 x 76, 114 x 114, 120 x 120, 144 x 144 and 152 x 152 icon sizes. Without counting Spotlight and Settings icon if you don’t want the OS to interpolate them!

As far as naming convention goes, you can name the icons anything you want as long as they are the correct size (and that high-res images use the @2x suffix). Just make sure that in your Info.plist file, you declare the names of the icons using the `CFBundleIconFiles` key.

[This similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17473485/ipad-how-to-create-a-different-icon-for-ios-7) on SO might also be of use to you.

**EDIT 1:** As per comment below, see here for more info:

- [iOS 7 Design Resources > iOS Human Interface Guidelines > Icon and Image Design > App Icon](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/AppIcons.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH19-SW1)
- [iOS App Programming Guide > App-Related Resources > App Icons](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/App-RelatedResources/App-RelatedResources.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH6-SW1)

**EDIT 2:** If you are using Xcode 5, select the target then select the General tab and you can see the dimensions of the required icons in the App Icons section. See the Apple doco about [Asset Catalogs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-image_catalog-1.0/Recipe.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013303-CH1-SW1) (in particular [see this section](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-image_catalog-1.0/StoringAppIconsandLaunchImagesinanAssetCatalog/StoringAppIconsandLaunchImagesinanAssetCatalog.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013303-CH7-SW1)) where it shows this screenshot:

[image: Xcode 5 screenshot]

Comment: Plist does not require @2x to be included. The confusion remains about the 120 x 120 size - how does one account for it? Since it is retina one is not sure whether iOS reads it from plist. OTOH, there is no 60X60 icon image that will be included in plist. Confusion.

Comment: You should read the iOS7 design resources available from the Apple Developer Center. It explains all this, but I did not quote it in my answer because it's pre-release doco. See [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/AppIcons.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH19-SW1) and [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/App-RelatedResources/App-RelatedResources.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH6-SW1).

Answer (score 6):

New icon image sizes that will be required for iOS 7, naming conventions are mentioned below.

For iPhone
"appicon-60.png,
appicon-60@2x.png"

For iPad
"appicon-76.png,
appicon-76@2x.png"

Spotlight search results icon for all devices
"appicon-Small-40.png,
appicon-Small-40@2x.png"

Answer (score 5):

What Apple mentioned in mail **"Your delivery was successful, but you may wish to correct the following issues in your next delivery:**"

This means this is not the a reason they will reject but they would like it to be corrected in next delivery.

Answer (score 5):

The Xcode GUI for specifying icons gives a concise overview of what icon sizes are supported (see below). Required icons will depend on the device(s) you choose to support.

[image]

Icon filename can be of your choosing as long as the dimensions are correct and you let Xcode know about the icon file via the GUI pictured or via the Info.plist.

Answer (score 4):

You need to give app icon size for iPhone in ios 7 is 60*60 for non retina and 120*120 for retina display. And you need to remeber the naming convention in ios7. And for more info see in this image...

[image]

And for more info see this link

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconMatrix.html

Comment: Can you give the source of this image ?

Comment: see this link this is updated link   https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconMatrix.html

Comment: Sure, no Icon-60@2x.png in updated doc, I had to add Icon to Info.plist in order to make an xcode validation warning "120px icon not found" disappear.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way would be to use AppIcon set. Here is online tool, [Icons Master](http://imageresier-agrastas.rhcloud.com), which will create AppIcon.appiconset folder and it takes care size and naming convection for the icons.

Answer (score 0):

In **Images.xcassets** if you give the images with proper sizes XCode never throws any warning of any error, Make sure that the size of the images is proper.

Possibilities of throwing warning/error

- If you miss any of the images even if you miss single image it throws warning.
- If the size of the image does not match with the required size.