# iOS 7 app validation issue

Tags: ios

I am trying to submit my app to app store .but I am getting following error

[image]

Here is plist file:

Can Anyone tell we the reason for this error. I have deleted my all icons and re-added to project but still same error coming.

Comment: Clean the project and then build it. If you not succeed with this change then try to restart the xcode .

Comment: here it is a solution:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18736954/missing-recommended-icon-file-the-bundle-does-not-contain-an-app-icon-for-iph/18737063#18737063

Comment: "Here is plist file:" Where is the plist file? Have you missed it out? "Can Anyone tell we the reason for this error" **EASY** `Invalid Image Path - No image found at the path referenced under key 'CFBundleIcons': 'icon-**'` sounds like it explains itself. Is your real question - How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: I am able to resolve the bug. 
I have deleted icons key from my plist file and then I used "Use Asset Catalog"  option form Xcode 5. Using Asset catalog all my icons and splash images group into a single bundle.

Answer (score 1):

You have to make a Images.xcassets for make you sure you got all types of images: like this:
[link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QHIlN.png)

This can be a useful link :[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18523193/ios-app-submission-invalid-image-sizes)

> If you want to target only iOS 7, you just need 76 x 76, 120 x 120 and
>   152 x 152 icon sizes. If you want to target also iOS 6, you’ll need 57
>   x 57, 72 x 72, 76 x 76, 114 x 114, 120 x 120, 144 x 144 and 152 x 152
>   icon sizes. Without counting Spotlight and Settings icon if you don’t
>   want the OS to interpolate them!

another useful link: [link](http://blog.manbolo.com/2013/08/15/new-metrics-for-ios-7-app-icons)

Answer (score 1):

you may have deleted your `images` from your previous location,, if  so drag and drop it to your project and select

> Copy items into destination group's folder (if indeed)

else
[Details of icons for iphone/ipad](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1686/_index.html)