# Why Apps icon disappear after update iOS 7.

Tags: ios, ios7, uiimage, icons

I match a strange problem，when device update iOS 7, my Apps icon disappear and iOS 6 is ok.

[image: after update iOS 7 Apps icon is default]

Anything setting error? or miss piex image ?

Thanks advance!

Comment: Because the Icon size have been Changed in ios 7

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18523193/ios-app-submission-invalid-image-sizes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For IOS 7 you need to add a new icons.

[image]

Add new images in the size of 76x76 , 120 x 120 and 152x 152

Refer this

[image]