# How to fix ERROR ITMS 90032, 90022, 90363, 90394, on submitting app to App Store?

Tags: xcode, swift, icons, swift2, watchkit

I tried to submit new version of my application to the App Store, but unexpectedly I got some errors. I tried to fix them but it's not working, even I searched online and I still didn't find anything to help me. To fix icons I'm using application called [Prepo](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/prepo/id476533227?mt=12) (<-- click to check it), every time that I used Prepo it worked, so I don't know what is problem.

You can check pictures.

> **Here are Errors.**
>   [image]
>
> **Here is my info.Plist.**
>   [image]
>
> **iOS App Icons.**
>   [image]
>
> **WatchOS App Icons.**
>   [image]

I used Images to be more clear to you, I hope you can help me.

Answer (score 1):

You should not have any icons labeled as "iPad" in your WatchOS App Icons as an apple watch cannot be paired with an iPad. [ITMS-90032](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28165916/error-itms-90032invalid-image-path-no-image-found-at-the-path-referenced-und)

Where there is a **Missing required icon file**, you should provide an app icon of that size in your asset catalog. Just size down one of your larger app icons to that size.