# Invalid image path Xcode:7.2.1

Tags: xcode, ionic-framework

I am doing ionic app debugging. After the debug and all. I am trying to release an update to app store, but It works perfectly in iPhone6 emulator. The following errors shows up.

[This error shows up when i am trying to add this to app store.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JCV8D.png)

I have already sent few updates before this, and there were not such errors.

Answer (score 1):

Ionic use cordova and since cordova 6.0, there is a bug on the iOS builder 4.1.0.
You can temporally downgrade cordova or iOS builder until this bug will be fixed

to downgrade cordova (and so downgrade iOS builder)

```
sudo npm uninstall -g 
sudo npm install -g cordova@5.4.1
```

**OR**

to downgrade only ios

```
sudo ionic platform rm ios
sudo ionic platform add ios@3.9.2
```

to check iOS version

```
sudo ionic platforms
```

Answer (score 0):

It didn't find any icon for one of the resolutions your app supports
Try by regenerating icons from [Ionic CLI](http://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/icon-splashscreen.html):

```
$ ionic resources --icon
```

Build again for the iOS plateform

After this make sure there is icons in the resources folder of your app:
ios - App name folder - Resources - icons

Another solutiion try to delete the CFBundleIconFile from the info.plist file : [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35283545/4557505)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. But it is still not working. May I know any another way to solve?

Comment: you can delete CFBundleIconFile key from info.plist, reference: this solution worked for the other users of cordova so it may work for you also: stackoverflow.com/a/35283545/4557505