# Errors on Apple App Store submission

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-build

I am currently deploying my first application to the Apple app store. I have gone through the provisioning profile, development profile set up and distribution certificates and I finally got as far as to be able to upload the app to the app store, but now it is giving me these errors:

=====================================================

**ERROR ITMS-90032:** "Invalid Image Path - No image found at the path referenced under key 'CFBundleIconFile': 'icon.png'"
**ERROR ITMS-90032:** "Invalid Image Path - No image found at the path referenced under key 'CFBundleIconFile': 'icon.png'"

=====================================================

**ERROR ITMS-90023:** "Missing required icon file. The bundle does not contain an app icon for iPad of exactly '76x76' pixels, in .png format for iOS versions >= 7.0."
**ERROR ITMS-90023:** "Missing required icon file. The bundle does not contain an app icon for iPad of exactly '76x76' pixels, in .png format for iOS versions >= 7.0."

=====================================================

**ERROR ITMS-90023:** "Missing required icon file. The bundle does not contain an app icon for iPad of exactly '152x152' pixels, in .png format for iOS versions >= 7.0."
**ERROR ITMS-90023:** "Missing required icon file. The bundle does not contain an app icon for iPad of exactly '152x152' pixels, in .png format for iOS versions >= 7.0."

=====================================================

**ERROR ITMS-90474:** "Invalid Bundle. iPad Multitasking support requires these orientations: 'UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait,UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown,UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft,UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight'. Found 'UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft,UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight' in bundle 'coza.companyname.appname'."
**ERROR ITMS-90474:** "Invalid Bundle. iPad Multitasking support requires these orientations: 'UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait,UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown,UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft,UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight'. Found 'UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft,UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight' in bundle 'coza.companyname.appname'."

=====================================================

**ERROR ITMS-90475:** "Invalid Bundle. iPad Multitasking support requires launch story board in bundle 'coza.companyname.appname'."
**ERROR ITMS-90475:** "Invalid Bundle. iPad Multitasking support requires launch story board in bundle 'coza.companyname.appname'."

I have Googled and tried suggestions but still exactly the same errors come up. Things I have tried is clearing up legacy options in the info-plist file as well as selecting all device orientation options and deselecting them, but I still get the same errors.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: see this once it helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28165916/error-itms-90032invalid-image-path-no-image-found-at-the-path-referenced-und

Comment: Thanks @Anbu.Karthik . I went through them and changed/removed the bad keys, etc but it is still giving me exactly the same error. Even when I removed the CFBundleIconFile completely. This makes me think that somehow when I change things on the info.plist file it is not saving. Am I doing something wrong? Sorry for noob, but this is my first submission.