# ERROR ITMS-900032: "Invalid Image Path - "

Tags: ios, xcode

The full text of the error message is [image]

Where do I find the setting CFBundleIconFile and how do I associate it with the icon.png file that does exist in what I assume to be the assets folder?

Answer (score 0):

You read the code wrongly and  generated a duplicated topic. Your response is here:

[ERROR ITMS-90032:"Invalid Image Path - No image found at the path referenced under key 'CFBundleIcons':AppIcon40x40"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28165916/error-itms-90032invalid-image-path-no-image-found-at-the-path-referenced-und)