# having problems posting to the Apple store

Tags: ios, xamarin

I am using Xamarin and I am having problems posting to the apple store.
I got 4 errors :
ERROR ITMS-90022: "Missing required icon file. The bundle does not contain an app icon for iPhone / iPod Touch of exactly '120x120' pixels, in .png format for iOS versions >= 10.0."

ERROR ITMS-90023: "Missing required icon file. The bundle does not contain an app icon for iPad of exactly '167x167' pixels, in .png format for iOS versions supporting iPad Pro."

ERROR ITMS-90023: "Missing required icon file. The bundle does not contain an app icon for iPad of exactly '152x152' pixels, in .png format for iOS versions >= 10.0."

ERROR ITMS-90474: "Invalid Bundle. iPad Multitasking support requires these orientations: 'UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait,UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown,UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft,UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight'. Found 'UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait' in bundle ...

the 1st 3 I make icons that fix the pixels they want but I do not know where to place them...
in info.plist there is not a place for them...

and the last one,
I do not know what they are asking from

any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

App icons are managed through the Assets.xcassets folder in your Xcode project.  The AppIcons image will show different sizes where you can drag and drop each properly sized icon right into place.

Check about 1/3 of the way down [in this guide](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/application_fundamentals/working_with_images/app-icons/) for some more details on how to do it with Xamarin.

Device orientations are managed through property lists.  Check out the section on [device deployment here.](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/application_fundamentals/working_with_property_lists/)

Comment: I went back and added the icons to the right places and I remake the .api but I am still getting the same errors and I do not know why.

Comment: ok, so I clear all the builds and redid it and not those errors are gone, but now I have a new error  Error ITMS-90032: "Invalid Image Path - No image found at the path referenced under key 'CFBundleIcons': 'AppIcon40X40'" any ideas ?

Comment: Try any of the answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28165916/error-itms-90032invalid-image-path-no-image-found-at-the-path-referenced-und

Answer (score 0):

For the last one, iPad Multitasking support requires all the orientations but your app does not,so just add the UIRequiresFullScreen key to your Xcode project’s Info.plist file and apply the Boolean value YES,

or you can select all the device orientations-

-> Portrait

-> Upside Down

-> Landscape Left

-> Landscape Right

Answer (score 0):

Try switch off "optimize PNG" checkbox on the iOS Build tab of Preferences of your iOS project. It worked for me.